# How to avoid downtime while running job simultaneously in bamboo

Tags: deployment, ansible, sap-commerce-cloud, bamboo, bamboo-artifacts

[Service has stopped in both the nodes, I just want everything else to be done simultaneously but there should not be any down time, Could someone please help me to solve this. Job is set up in Bamboo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLkjc.jpg)

Comment: Please do not provide code, logs, output, error messages... in images: in most cases it is barely readable, it impairs search engines ability to index the content, it prevents people trying to help you to copy/paste content if needed, it uses (in best cases...) 1000 times more data volume (e.g. disk space to store, data transfers....) than the equivalent text in code/citation block... and above all, it is specifically listed as a bad practice in [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure ansible to provision the hosts one by one by adding this to your playbook:

```
serial: 1
```

Docs: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#setting-the-batch-size-with-serial

This assumes that your playbook has tasks for bringing the service up after stopping it and before proceeding to the next host.